iOS App (built in ReactJS + Capacitor) stops working when I add Firebase Auth
I have a ReactJS App that works well on web and Android, but does not load on iOS, all I get is a white screen. In order to debug I did a create-react-app app with a simple document fetch from Firebase. Everything works well when I only initialise the database in firebase.js, like so:
 // src/firebase.js
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";

const firebaseConfig = {

};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = getFirestore(app);

export { db };

but as soon as I add the Auth to it, it stops working. The data simply never loads, even though Im not even using the auth in the app, just initializing it.
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";

When I add a console log to confirm the initialisation, it shows up in the console without problems
console.log("Firebase Auth Initialized:", auth);

I have added GoogleServices-Info.plist file to Xcode, and added Keychain Signing to the app.
I have no idea what else I could try... any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

I recommend that you use the native Firebase SDK under Android and iOS. There are already various Capacitor plugins that will help you with this.

@RGe Omg! I didn't even know that was an option. Yes, that worked immediately!!! Thank you so much!

@RGe the app loads now, but I noticed that some things are not loading from firebase storage, whenever the security rule is set to request.auth != null;, even though the user is logged in. Am I missing something obvious here? Thank you so much for any suggestions!

Do you also use the Capacitor Firebase Storage plugin? If you use the Firebase Android/iOS SDK for Auth you also need to use the Firebase Android/iOS SDK for Storage.
